# Prevent system from canceling restart if an application prevents system from restarting

Tags: windows-10

**Is there a way prevent system timeout reboot/shutdown process if some application is not responding/preventing from closing itself?**

When user initiated system restart, the system starts closing applications while showing "restarting" screen, where it shows a list of running applications. If an application shows some kind of prompt (or simply exits too slowly: I'm looking at your GDrive) the restart/shutdown down process waits a minute or so and cancels itself returning back to Windows session.

This is an unwanted behaviour, not only it doesn't necessarily shows/focus on the application that prevented restart, but also if user stepped away from computer, there is a good chance they won't be able tell if system was restarted or not.

I believe Windows 7 had a hidden setting that would allow forcibly kill such applications after certain time, or at least it would stay in restart screen indefinitely until user cancels it or approves forced restart without waiting.

*To reproduce the situation, open Notepad, type anything and without saving try reboot the computer. After about 1 minute reboot will be canceled.*

Comment: Can you tell the software?? In my Windows 10, I have many software that give prompt when closing, and restarting shows the applications that could not be closed, but within seconds, it automatically force closes and restarts...

Comment: @BhavyaGupta For example Notepad, open it, type a letter and without saving do system restart.

Comment: @vanowm in that case it is more generally unwanted to reboot without saving rather than kill. You *can* kill from that list of running applications.

Comment: @vanowm, I got your problem.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'd be happy if it simply let me decide what to do, instead of automatically going back to windows and pretend like nothing happened, even though 99% other applications/services are no longer running.

Comment: @vanowm Please see this post, by Brink also "2) Change HungAppTimeout to "1000"." : https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97821-turn-autoendtasks-restart-shut-down-sign-out-windows-10-a-post1206197.html#post1206197

Comment: @vssher that setting will prevent you from force close applications or cancel reboot for the time it set to. So "1000" will add 1 second before "Closing nn app and restarting" screen times out.

Answer (score 0):

Open Regedit (Win+R).
Go to - HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop\
Right click in right pane and select add a new entry and select "String Value".
Rename it to `AutoEndTasks`.
Change its value to 1.
It should automatically force shutdown apps.

Comment: Unfortunately it kills applications instantly without any wait whatsoever. Not quiet the desired effect, but it's a start I guess..

Comment: @vanowm There is also another command you can use along side of the AutoEndTasks, __HungAppTimeout__ (default = 5 seconds). A page by Shawn Brink at TenForums https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97842-change-hungapptimeout-value-windows-10-a.html  Also, vanowm, that is an awesome photo, very funny, I needed that, thanks ;-)